# Create users using AWS Cognito and Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-cognito

I'm making an application using Django (Backend) and ReactJS (Frontend). The application will be hosted on AWS. I want to use AWS Cognito to allow users to login to the site.

I'm trying to find out whether users can create accounts/sign up directly from my app instead of me manually creating one in the AWS User Pool.

I know that there is support for this on Android, iOS and JavaScript.

Is there a way to do this on Django as well? I am unable to find a library that allows me to do this.

If not, is there a recommended similar service like AWS Cognito that can be used with Django?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can create users from the Django app.
First your need to experiment on [boto3 Cognito idp](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_create_user) at Django shell.
After learning about the required parameters, you can easily add users to pool from Django.

I am sharing on-hand experience to integrate Cognito with Django with implementing my own library.

Comment: Where is your library? Could you share it @Saiful Azad

Comment: It is not mine. https://github.com/labd/django-cognito-jwt.
Have a look.